# SwiftUI NavigationLink Button is gray and untouchable

Tags: swiftui, navigationlink

I can not get a `NavigationLink` in SwiftUI. The button is visible, but unfortunately this is gray and can not be clicked.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail for Test")) {
                    Text("Test")
            }.navigationBarTitle("Select a user")
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 8):

It seems the problem is related to the fact that you have added the `NavigationLink` inside the `NavigationView` without defining a layout

In fact, if you add a `VStack`, everything works correctly

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Destination()) {
                        Text("Test")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Select a user")
        }
    }
}

struct Destination: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Ok")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is related to a missing view in your NavigationLink statement.

```
...

NavigationLink(destination: NeedsAView()) {
    Text("Test")
}.navigationBarTitle("Select a user")

...

struct NeedsAView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello Destination")
    }
}
```